# What is it called when all the characters are typed out for typeface examination?

Tags: terminology, typefaces

Sometimes when choosing typefaces, it is helpful to examine all the characters so you aren't surprised when (for example) the dollar sign looks unusual.

Beyond typing "the quick brown fox", what is the process called?

Are there any webpages or applications that will help see all the characters quickly?

Comment: The major Adobe design applications have the Glyphs panel, Microsoft Word has a similar feature (was it "Insert Symbol"?). Windows has "Character Map"; Mac OS X has FontBook. Of course it's a staple function of Font editors such as FontForge (free) and FontLab (*not* free).  There may be countless free third party applications as well, as it's not that hard to create. (I wrote my own which also lists OpenType features. Now *that* was hard.)

Answer (score 5):

A 'Character Map' can also describe the feature as seen on [Fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/futura/light).

Comment: This is also what it's called in [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map_(Windows)) and [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Character_Map)

Answer (score 3):

They are called *type specimens*, most type foundries provide type specimen sheets, these days they are PDF.

The "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is a special case of *Lorem Ipsum* that contains all the letters of the English alphabet.

And "yes" a Character Map or Character Palette program is a quick way to display glyphs that is bundled as part of every major operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all font foundry and font sales sites offer a display of all glyphs in a font.

For example, [myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/)...

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/helvetica/pro-regular/glyphs.html

[image]

I'm not certain there's a *specific* name for it.... glyph index.... Character Table....

Comment: Yes, but what is it *called*? You're not answering the question here :)